# deploy a php project from visual studio team services (visual studio online) to centos 6 vps

Tags: php, azure, deployment, azure-devops, centos6

I have a php project; for which I want to use visual studio team services as Code Source Version Controller and take advantage of it :project management feature and  automate release management(deployement). The problem I am facing is all the article I get only explain how to deploy a project(not php) to Azure but my server is a centos 6 vps.

My questions are:
Is it possible to deploy(test and production) a php project from VSTS to a centos 6 vps? 
if yes; Can it be automate using release management? and are there any link to a documentation that can help.

Comment: How do you deploy your PHP project to VPS before?

Comment: @Eddie; I do it using filezila; which is manual

Comment: So you are using FTP method?

Comment: Yes, I am using FTP and the project is not yet in Visual Studio Team services. I want to upload it so that a team of developpers can work on it; seeing their tasks,....

Comment: This question should be moved to devops.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the FTP method to deploy your PHP project to VPS via [FTP Uploader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task) task. Install this extension to your account and add the task in build/release definition.

Comment: FTP Uploader seems to have problem from user review.

Comment: @aidonsnous What do you mean?

Comment: "Doesn't even appear as a task for use in Build or Release Management when using Visual Studio Team Services"

Comment: @aidonsnous I didn't see this issue at my side, it can work correctly.